# Non-linear first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution of this equation

$$
4[y'(t)]^2+y(t)y'(t) = 0
$$

My reasoning is the following: I can write it as

$$
y'(t)\big(4y'(t)+y(t)\big) = 0
$$

therefore either $y'(t) = 0 \Longrightarrow y(t) = y_0$ or $4y'(t)+y(t) = 0 \Longrightarrow \frac{dy}{y} = -\frac{dt}{4}$

which leads to two conditions (either one or the other or both must be satisfied)
$$
\begin{cases}
y(t) = y_0\\
y(t) = y_1e^{-\frac{1}{4}t}
\end{cases}$$

so the general solution would be

$$
y(t) = y_0 + y_1 e^{-\frac{1}{4}t}
$$

**My question**

Is this it or I lost some solutions by solving it this way? Is there a general method for solving this kind of equations?

Comment: Since the equation is not linear one cannot expect the sum of the solutions to be a solution. I.e., when both $y_0$ and $y_1$ are non-zero your sum does not satisfy the equation.

Comment: @Andrea. In your case there are no other solutions. Your method is general enough. The only possible problem is when solutions from two branches may have common points, then piecewise solutions may exist. In your problem it is not so, because the only possible common point is $y(t_1)=0$, that leads to solution $y(t)=0$ which is common for two branches.

Comment: I've meant that there are no other solutions than $y(t)=y_0$ and $y(t)=y_1 \exp(-\frac{t}{4})$. Their sum is not solution except "zero case".

Comment: Thank you very much. So basically how would I express the general solution if I wanted to?

Comment: @Andrea There is no expression for the general solution, because there are two separate families of solutions that comprise the general solution.

Comment: thank you very much!